# SQLiteException «logic error near "ON"» when creating a trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, nhibernate

I'm trying to use SQLite to run NHibernate integration tests. NHibernate's `SchemaExport` will set up the database for me based on my mapping files. This works fine, except for my triggers. Here's what such a trigger in an `.hbm` file looks like:

```xml
<database-object>
  <create>
    CREATE TRIGGER TR_PersonInserted ON Person AFTER INSERT AS
    BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON

      UPDATE Person 
      SET    ModifiedDate = GetDate(), CreatedDate = GetDate() 
      FROM   inserted 
      WHERE  Person.PersonId = inserted.PersonId

      SET NOCOUNT OFF
    END
  </create>
  <drop>
  </drop>
</database-object>
```

This works great in SQL Server 2012.

Without this trigger the `SchemaExport` also works fine when using SQLite. *With* this trigger though, I get an exception when creating the schema:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQL logic error or missing database near "ON": syntax error

This is not very descriptive. I've tried several things to get a bit further, including:

- Removing the contents (i.e. everything between `BEGIN` and `END`)
- Removing the `AS` statement
- Removing the `ON` statement
- Removing the underscore from the trigger name
- Adding a `;` before the statement

Nothing seems to help.

What am I missing? What is the correct syntax for a trigger in SQLite?

I'd prefer a solution that also works fine in SQL-Server-2012, but am not fussed about that as I can create a different trigger per database dialect if needs be.

PS. I'm using the NuGet package for [System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [SQLite's CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) accepts syntax in the form

```
CREATE TRIGGER t AFTER INSERT ON x
BEGIN {stmts} END
```

whereas [SQL Server's CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), and the provided schema, is in the form

```
CREATE TRIGGER t ON x AFTER INSERT
AS {stmts}
```

Normalizing the two different syntax forms across the different database engine does not seem practical with a directly specified SQL DDL, especially considering other differences such as lack of SET NOCOUNT in SQLite.

To put this into a full example based of your specific case, this would come down to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_PersonInserted INSERT ON Person
BEGIN
  UPDATE Person 
  SET    ModifiedDate = DATETIME('NOW'), CreatedDate = DATETIME('NOW')
  WHERE  PersonId = new.PersonId;
END
```

Comment: @Jeroen Cool :) On to different problems!

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks! I'm a fan of improving answers.